# Fisher convergence as sample goes to infinity.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, fisher-information

I was wondering how does the Fisher law behave when $n => \inf.$.
$F_{q, n-p} = \frac{SSE_0-SSE/q}{SSE/(n-p)}$ I expect the test statistics goes lower as n goes up but does the pdf of the law converges to something particular like a gaussian or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure of your notation, but I hope this answers your question.

An $F$ distribution with degrees of freedom $m$ and $n$ is the ratio of two independent random variables.
The numerator is $Q_m$ with $mQ_m \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(m).$ That is, $Q_m$ is a chi-squared random variable divided by its degrees of freedom. Similarly,
the denominator is $Q_n$ with $nQ_n \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n).$

As $n \rightarrow \infty,$ the denominator random variable $Q_n$ converges
in probability to $1.$ Thus, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $m$ is held fixed,
$F = Q_m/Q_n$ converges in distribution to $Q_m.$

The figure below shows the density function of $\mathsf{F}(5, 1000)$ in
black and the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(5)$ divided by $5$ as
a broken red curve.  Of course $n = 1000$ is not quite $\infty,$ but (I hope)
large enough to make the point.

[image]

The figure below shows a sequence of densities of chi-squared distributions,
divided by degrees of freedom, to illustrate increasing concentration about $1$
as DF increases.
Degrees of freedom are 10, 20, 50, 100, and 500, plotted in blue, green, orange,
red, and black, respectively.

[image]

Comment: So that means that as n goes to infinity the denominator basically becomes 1 but the numerator gets to be $X1/n1$     $with X1 = Chisq(n1)$ ? It looks like it's converging to a gaussian seeing the black curve. (altough not centered nor scaled)

Comment: Roughly speaking, Yes: A chi-sqared distribution is the sum of DF iid RV's (squared std normals), so by the CLT a sequence of standardized chi-squared random variables with increasing DFs converges to standard normal. Although dividing by DFs (as here) centers the chi-squareds at 1 (not 0) and makes the SDs converge to 0 (not stabilize at 1), you are seeing something like the 'CLT effect' in the _shapes_ of the distributions in the second figure.